# linux command "getent" not returning all numeric usernames (ex. 10798) in linux file system

Tags: linux, bash

i am using "getent" command to fetch user information in my linux file system.

I have a user with the username "10798" and another user with the username "user" and user ID "10798",i am using getent command to fetch the user info of user with the name "10798"

but the command is not giving any output

I think the command "getent" will only look for the user id number if you give all numeric value as input to the command

here is the scenario

```
# cat /etc/passwd
10798:x:10799:10799::/home/10798:/bin/bash
user:x:10798:10798::/home/user:/bin/bash
# getent passwd 10798
user:x:10798:10798::/home/user:/bin/bash
```

how to get the user with the username 10798 using the getent command

passwd    When no key is provided, use setpwent(3), getpwent(3),
                    and endpwent(3) to enumerate the passwd database.  When
                    one or more key arguments are provided, pass each
                    numeric key to getpwuid(3) and each nonnumeric key to
                    getpwnam(3) and display the result.

I got this from the linux man page is there a way to redirect numeric keys to getpwnam

Comment: `getent passwd | grep '^10798:'`.

Comment: it works fine ..... thanks @Cyrus

Answer (score 0):

ls already performs that lookup. You can perform a user information lookup from the command line with [getent passwd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/how-can-i-look-up-a-username-by-id-in-linux/36582#36582).

If ls shows a user ID instead of a user name, it's because there's no user by that name. Filesystems store user IDs, not user names. If you mount a filesystem from another system, or if a file belongs to a now-deleted user, or if you passed a numerical user ID to chown, you can have a file that belongs to a user ID that doesn't have a name.

On a shared host, you may have access to some files that are shared between several virtual machines, each with their user database. This is a bit weird (why share files but not the users that own them?), but it's technically possible.

Comment: passwd :   When no key is provided, use setpwent(3), getpwent(3),
and endpwent(3) to enumerate the passwd database When one or more key arguments are provided, pass each
numeric key to getpwuid(3) and each nonnumeric key to
getpwnam(3) and display the result.                                                        I got this from the linux man page is there a way to pass nonnumeric key to getpwnam in the command getent